# Tensorflow File Operations with Tensor String Input

Tags: input, tensorflow, dataset, python-multithreading, tensor

I was trying to use tensorflow [tf.gfile](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r1.5/api_docs/python/tf/gfile) functions such as, ListDirectory, [walk](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r1.5/api_docs/python/tf/gfile/Walk) etc..
I was wondering why they cannot have tensor string input? Am I missing something?

I am trying to read all images from a folder and stack a tensor as an input data.

```
def input_parser(dir_name, label):
    ret_stack = []
    for parent, dirnames, filenames in tf.gfile.Walk(dir_name):
    ...
       img = file_read_operation(filenames)
       ret_stack.append(img)
    return tf.stack(ret_stack), label
...

#train_dir list including folder names
tr_data = Dataset.from_tensor_slices((train_dir, train_labels))
tr_data = tr_data.map(input_parser)
iterator = Iterator.from_structure(tr_data.output_types, tr_data.output_shapes)
next_element = iterator.get_next()

training_init_op = iterator.make_initializer(tr_data)
...
...
elem1, elem2 = sess.run(next_element)
```

I want my mapping function to read files in given location and stack them into tensor.

Comment: Welcome at SO. Please finish the tour and you will understand that we are not a "do your homework" site. Read [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and modify question accordingly to minimal working example. Without posting your code you risk removal of your question. With your stated trail code and error... people are more willing to help you so both can learn. Enjoy SO ;-)

Comment: I don't understand ZF007's comment, and don't know what "trail code" is. Better if folks would try to answer the question, rather than just downvote.  Y.Mustafa's question seems good.  Always seek code best-practice if you can.  The "walk" option looks like it could be used to load multiple images.  Tensorflow learning curve is very steep and harsh, even for those who have built working NN's.  I got here doing research on how best to load images. MNIST tutorial flattens them & is one-hot.  Advanced MNIST tutorial might be helpful:  https://www.tensorflow.org/get_started/mnist/pros.

Comment: @ZF007, thanks for reply, I modified the question

Comment: your welcome... and its much improved. Well done!

Comment: @gemesyscanada.. "trail" & error... rings a bell? I can use wordings like "experimental code".. which offend obviously coders that are on revision X.Y of there code and have 10.000 hours of coding experience. But I see partially your point about grammer... moving "code" behind the word "error" as intended.